# Trying to send special characters via JQuery Ajax to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending special characters to a PHP file via JQuery Ajax.

**send_to_process.js**

```
var special_charac = '!@#$%^&*()_+-=';
var dataString = 'data=' + special_charac;

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./process.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function (result) {

                }
            });
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

$data= $_POST['data'];
echo $data;

?>
```

In the PHP file I'm getting all values except **+** and **&**

Why is it so ?

Does JQuery Ajax has got some limitations as to what data can you send to PHP script ?

Comment: Try escaping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not AJAX limitations. These are URL limitations. eg & is used to split parameters.
Just send data as json object

not:

```
data: dataString,
```

but

```
data: {data: special_charac}
```

or use [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) function to escape data

```
var dataString = 'data=' + encodeURI(special_charac);
```